# Making a HTML source object

Tags: javascript, html, object, web-component, custom-element

I want to create a little HTML extension which provides a tag (`uai`) which will be formatted like `<uai src="some_what_file.mp3" controller="nav" autoplay="true">`

And so on this tag will get a javascript object assigned.

```
function uai(){
    this.src = { ... }
    this.controller = { ... }
    this.autoplay = { ... }
}
```

But I wonder how I will apply this function as an object to the html tag and make the HTML tag to apply the source to `this.src`

This object will be similar to the input tag *

---

I know the audio tag exists, and I fully know how to use it. But I want to replace the audio tag and functions with this one. It will make it easier for me to make canvas supported audio marks, so that's why I need it.

Comment: look into web components, specifically `document.registerElement`... you can use setters to bind the dom attribs to the object instance and use old-school mutation events (or a MutationObserver) to monitor the attribs.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/registerElement and http://webcomponents.org/articles/introduction-to-custom-elements/

Comment: You are trying to reprogram the browser (replacing tags) and this can't be done. Where you are trying to add elements, this is a new feature not available everywhere or is unstable. Be aware of these things.

Comment: @Rob Not trying to replace a tag, just trying to create a tag which possibly one day would be imported as an API more commonly than the audio tag is used :)

Comment: What does UAI mean?

Comment: @Supersharp it means `ultimate audio interface`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Custom Elements you need to insert an hyphen `-` in the name of your tag to be sure it won't be used in the future standard, for example: `<ultimate-audio>`.

Also you should use now the [version 1](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/customelements) of the Custom Elements specification, which uses `customElements.define()` instead of `document.registerElement()` to register a new element.

Last, you cannot use the `extends:'audio'` option if you want to create a new tag.

You can use the `class` definition in all modern browsers:

Content of *ulimate-audio.html*:

```
<template>
    <h3>UAI</h3>
    <nav>
        <button id=PlayBtn>Play</button>
        <button id=StopBtn>Stop</button>
        <input id=AutoplayCB type=checkbox disabled>Auto-Play
        <div>Source : <output id=SourceOut></output></div>
    </nav>
</template>

<script>
( function ( owner )
{
    class UAI extends HTMLElement 
    {
        constructor ()
        {
            super()
            this.model = {}
            this.view = {}
        }

        connectedCallback ()
        {
          //View
            this.innerHTML = owner.querySelector( 'template' ).innerHTML
            this.view.autoplay = this.querySelector( '#AutoplayCB' )
            this.view.source = this.querySelector( '#SourceOut' )

          //Model
            //autoplay
            var attr =  this.getAttribute( 'autoplay' ) 
            this.model.autoplay =  typeof attr == 'string' && ( attr == '' || attr == 'true' ) 

            //source
            this.model.source = this.getAttribute( 'src' )


          //Model -> View
            this.view.source.textContent = this.model.source
            this.view.autoplay.checked = this.model.autoplay

          //[play] event
            var self = this
            this.querySelector( '#PlayBtn' ).addEventListener( 'click', function () 
            {
                self.play() 
            } )
            this.querySelector( '#StopBtn' ).addEventListener( 'click', function () 
            {
                self.stop() 
            } )

          //init
            if ( this.model.autoplay )
                this.play()
        }

        play ()
        {   
            this.model.audio = new Audio( this.model.source )
            this.model.audio.play()
        }

        stop ()
        {
            this.model.audio.pause()
        }

        set src ( file ) 
        {
            console.log( '%s.src=%s', this, file )
            this.model.source = file
            this.model.audio.src = file 
            this.view.source.textContent = file
            if ( this.model.autoplay )
                this.model.audio.play()
        }

        set autoplay ( value )
        {
            console.warn( 'autoplay=', value )
            this.model.autoplay = ( value === "true" || value === true )
            this.view.autoplay.checked = this.model.autoplay
        }

    }

    customElements.define( 'ultimate-audio', UAI )
} )( document.currentScript.ownerDocument ) 
</script>
```

The UI of you control is defined in the `<template>`, where you can add a `<style>` element.
Then you can use your tag like this:

In the `header`, include the custom element:

```
<link rel="import" href="ultimate-audio.html">
```

In the `body`, use the new tag:

```
<ultimate-audio id=UA src="path/file.mp3" autoplay></ultimate-audio>
```

The methods `play()`, `stop()`, and the properties `src` and `autoplay` can be invoked form javascript:

```
UA.src = "path/file2.mp3"
UA.play()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just access it like you would any other element and do what you need to do with it.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('cookies').getAttribute('flavor'))
```

```html
<cookies flavor="chocolate chip"></cookies>
```

There are two important catches you should be aware of though:

First, it can't be self-closing. Browsers handle self-closing elements (`<cookies />`) in a special way, and you can't create custom self-closing tags (this is also a limitation that frameworks like Angular have to deal with). It has to have a closing tag, even if it has no children: `<cookies></cookies>`

Second, you can't do things like `document.querySelector('cookies').flavor` and access the property directly. You need to use `document.querySelector('cookies').getAttribute('flavor')` or `.setAttribute()`. You can however apply it yourself to use it latter:

```js
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('cookies'), 0).forEach(cookie => Object.defineProperty(cookie, 'flavor', {
  get: () => cookie.getAttribute('flavor'), 
  set: (value) => cookie.setAttribute('flavor', value)
}));

let cookie = document.querySelector('cookies');
console.log(cookie.flavor);
cookie.flavor = 'sugar';
console.log(cookie.flavor);
console.log(cookie);
```

```html
<cookies flavor="chocolate chip"></cookies>
<cookies flavor="peanut butter"></cookies>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a transpiler that support classes and extends is very easy.

```
class UAIElement extends HTMLElement {

}

document.registerElement('uai', UAIElement);
```

the plain js version:

```
document.registerElement('uai', {
  prototype: Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype, {
   extends: 'audio'
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for a such quick response.. But this would expect me to call the tag like `<uai> ... </uai>` is there any way I can call the tag like `<uai ... />`

Comment: (Sorry, it wont display, to low rep.)

Comment: Not, sure but i updated the answer with something i found on https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/#extendcustomeel I guess extending from a single tag element would do

Comment: then i think it wont be possible to do a single tag element, but if you extends from audio instead of img you would get many features native and out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) I will +1 this as soon as i get 15 rep's :)